# unclear forecast value for R timeseries

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am using hybridForecast R package , and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong to get a negative forecast:

example:

```
library("forecastHybrid")
hits=c(1969,2552,3407,3768,1302,2988,3760,2822,3012,2945,2979,3180,4421)
model <- hybridModel(y = hits)
fc <- forecast(model, h = 1)
plot(fc)

upper <- as.numeric(fc[["upper"]][1, 2]) #5107
lower <- as.numeric(fc[["lower"]][1, 2])# -24198
baseline <- as.numeric(fc["mean"][[1]]) # -2143
```

is there a reason for the negative forecast?

Comment: The main point of this prediction is the large confidence interval, so large that prediction is completely useless. A negative point estimate is not surprising in this case.

Comment: thanks. do you mean that the values are very different from each other? (I'm a developer not a statistician :( ). anything I can do?

Comment: The estimated model does not predict your data at all. You need to change model or... ask a statistician to help ! 8-)

Comment: "ask a statistician to help" - I was hoping to do it here :)

Comment: Here is an interesting link: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135061/best-method-for-short-time-series

Answer (score 1):

your vector is not a time series, so the `hybridModel` function is not able to fit a  model.

Try this, using the `ts` function.

```
hits=ts(c(1969,2552,3407,3768,1302,2988,3760,2822,3012,2945,2979,3180,4421), frequency=12)
model <- hybridModel(y = hits)
fc <- forecast(model, h = 1)
plot(fc)
```

The forecasts are "ok" (positive).

[image]